# Sharing one buffer - thread safe

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am not much into scheduling threads, i have like 4-5 threads and each of them will add data to one same buffer at random time.
How i can schedule the threads so there is no case two or more threads to access the buffer at same time ?
I am coding in C on Windows environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this C or C++ as you have a tag of boost?

Comment: C, sorry if thats wrong tag....

Comment: What kind of buffer - how is it organized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared buffer needs to be protected from concurrent reads/writes by different threads. A synchronization object should be used to prevent this from occuring. Anytime a thread wants to read from or write to the shared buffer it would acquire the lock, perform its operations on the shared buffer and release the lock once it no longers requires the buffer.

An example synchronization object would be [CriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
static CRITICAL_SECTION shared_buffer_lock;
static char shared_buffer[10];

int main()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&shared_buffer_lock);

    /* Start threads */
    ...

    /* Wait for threads */
    ...

    DeleteCriticalSection(&shared_buffer_lock);

    return 0;
}

/* In thread.. */

/* Obtain sole access to 'shared_buffer' */
EnterCriticalSection(&shared_buffer_lock);

/* Use 'shared_buffer' ... */

/* Release sole access of 'shared_buffer' */
LeaveCriticalSection(&shared_buffer_lock);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_mutex_t         mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int                     sharedData=0;

void *func(void *parm)
{
   int   rc;
   printf("Thread Entered\n");
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

   /********** Critical Section *******************/
   printf("Start critical section, holding lock\n");
   ++sharedData; 
   printf("End critical section, release lock\n");

   /********** Critical Section *******************/
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


}
```

The example above shows what you are looking for, using pthreads library. Acquire the mutex with pthread_mutex_lock and release it with pthread_mutex_unlock. All threads that request the same lock will be blocked until mutex is released. This guarantees that only one thread has access to your shared data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an exclusive access to the ressource (buffer). Under Windows I would use Mutexes for it (see CreateMutex and WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects in Windows API).